Clang putting parameter attribute before the return type?
According to https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#functions

LLVM function definitions consist of the “define” keyword, an optional linkage type, an optional runtime preemption specifier, an optional visibility style, an optional DLL storage class, an optional calling convention, an optional unnamed_addr attribute, a return type, an optional parameter attribute for the return type...

So, return type, then parameter attribute for the return type.
But given:
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
  return 0;
}

Clang emits:
define dso_local noundef i32 @main() #0 {

i32 is a return type and noundef is a parameter attribute, but the latter is being placed before the former.
What am I missing?

I aswered with a quick comment, but I think it warrants a proper answer… noundef i32 says that callers can rely on the return value not being undef. But why is that a parameter attribute, right?
Everything in LLVM is a Value. A return value is a Value that's provided by calling something, a parameter is a Value that's provided by a caller, 1+1 is a Value that's provided by adding two other values together, a global variable is a Value owns some RAM.
Because of this monomanic everything-is-a-value idea, attributes sort of belong to a Value. Most Values have a  computable 'noundef' status (x+y says it can be undef if either addend says it can be undef), parameters and return values are special in that the compiler frontend tells them what to say about their 'noundef' status via a bit of syntax: the attributes.
(Writing this makes me wonder about the load instruction. Can a load instruction be declared as noundef, if the compiler is sure that the global variable it reads is initialised at the time of reading. If it can't be declared as noundef now, someone will submit a patch next year, because conceptually, a load is just another Value and if there's any code in a pass that behaves specially wrt. undef, it should treat that load like a parameter… you get the idea.)

Right, that's fine as far as it goes, I'm clear on what the noundef is doing there. But why is it noundef i32 when the documentation says it should be i32 noundef?

Aah, I get it. Sorry about my stupidity yesterday, I grid-snapped to the parameter/notparameter issue and overlooked the placement. Perhaps I should delete the answer, I don't know the reason for the placement oddity (never have even looked at the code in that directory).
